# Maven Release Plugin not showing in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, release, devops

I installed Maven Release Plugin for Jenkins and Release plugin for Jenkins
[Maven Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin)
[Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin)
I restarted Jenkins many times after installation is done.

The problem is in a Maven Project Job, under "Build Environment" section I dont find the Maven Release Item.

[image]

[image]
Why I cant find the "perform maven release" item?

Can you help please?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason is that your job is not of type Maven Project.

When creating the project please select the type to be Maven Project:

[image: Create Maven Project job]

and then you will be able to see "Perform Maven Release" an extra menu option to start your Release Build:

[image: Perform Maven Release]

Comment: Can you add or more detail or otherwise expand on your point? That would increase the quality of your answer.